# How to return valid JSON array in WCF

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest, webinvoke

Here is my webInvoke

```
[WebInvoke(
        Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "{invoice}/{transtype}/"

        )
    ]
```

I have this return code

```
Dictionary<string, object> dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        dic.Add("ApprovalStatus", response.ApprovalStatus);
        dic.Add("AuthorizationCode", response.AuthorizationCode);
        dic.Add("CardBalance", response.CardBalance);
        dic.Add("ErrorMessage", response.ErrorMessage);
        dic.Add("InvoiceNumber", response.InvoiceNumber);

        return dic;
```

My problem is it does not return a valid JSON array

Sample result

```
 [{"Key":"ApprovalStatus","Value":"CAPTURED"},{"Key":"AuthorizationCode","Value":"TAS926"},{"Key":"CardBalance","Value":null},{"Key":"ErrorMessage","Value":""},{"Key":"InvoiceNumber","Value":"1"},{"Key":"ReferenceNumber","Value":"313506502708"},{"Key":"UniqueCode","Value":"2704"}]
```

How can I make this a JSON array?

Comment: It is a valid json array.....

Comment: @I4V, oh? I want something { "Data": [ "ApprovalStatus": "CAPTURED" ] }

Comment: But it is not a valid json. Your best bet would be `{ "Data": [ "ApprovalStatus", "CAPTURED" ] } `